# Microsoft Graph API - Mail.ReadBasic scope support for personal accounts (hotmail.com, live.com, outlook.com)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Using the MS Graph Explorer tool, it appears as though I am not able to consent to the `Mail.ReadBasic` scope for a @hotmail.com account.  When I click on the `Consent` button in the UI, the consent popup loads, but then immediately closes and consent is not granted.

If I sign in to the MS Graph Explorer tool with an account tied to an Azure AD tenant, I am able to successfully consent to the `Mail.ReadBasic` scope.

Additionally, trying to follow the user consent flow with an App Registration from my own tenant, I can run any request like the one below with an outlook.com, hotmail.com or live.com address and will see a 302 to my redirect URI with the message below.

REQUEST

```
GET /common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FMail.ReadBasic&state={state}&login_hint=some.name%40outlook.com
```

REDIRECT

```
302 {redirect_url}?error=invalid_scope&error_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20'scope'%20is%20not%20valid.%20The%20scope%20'https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadBasic'%20does%20not%20exist.&state={state}
```

The same requests using Azure AD tenant accounts will be successful.

Is the `Mail.ReadBasic` scope only supported for Azure AD tenant accounts and not personal accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mail.ReadBasic** is not supported for MSA accounts. Please Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions)

Comment: Thank you, I missed that in my search!  Are there any plans to support this scope for MSA accounts?

Comment: @ScottHill We will keep you posted about about this.